# Почему картинки съезжают при масштабировании?

Tags: html, css

При масштабировании нижние картинки съезжают https://uzinouzi.github.io/asdasd/ - Сам сайт

prntscr.com/h5btc6 - Вот макет, картинки и должны на хэдер залазить.

Но при масштабировании картинки влево смещаются: prntscr.com/h5bvg2
Без масштабирования все хорошо: prntscr.com/h5bul8

Answer (score 0):

У вас блок #section_one спозиционирован абсолютно, при увеличении экрана этот блок прилипает к левой стороне и занимает размер ребенка у которого 1920 ширина. Добавьте к нему left: 0 и right: 0;